# How to show errors from Web Service in Mule instead of Mule's error messages

Tags: web-services, mule, esb, mule-studio

For example if I make a wrong post/put directly to the web service it will give me this :

```
<prestashop>
   <errors>
      <error>
         <message><![CDATA[Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors.]]></message>
      </error>
   </errors>
</prestashop>
```

But if I pass by Mule ESB the error doesn't help me at all or the other developpers.

```
500 Internal Server Error
Unexpected character (R) at position 0.
Response code 404 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream
```

Here's my flow in Mule

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration_PrestaShop4"  host="host.org/api/customers/#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.string']" port="port" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" protocol="HTTPS">
    <http:basic-authentication username="keyU" password="keyP"/>
</http:request-config>

<flow name="prestaShopUpdateCustomerById">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8080" path="prestaShopUpdateCustomerById" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration_PrestaShop4" path="/" method="PUT" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
        </http:request-builder>          
    </http:request>
</flow>
```

Is it possible to make Mule show the webservice's error instead of this generic message (this question is both for REST and SOAP webservices).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a success-status-code-validator that covers all of the cases (you can then be more specific):
`<http:request path="path" method="method" config-ref="requestConfig">
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="0..599"/>
    </http:request>`
I hope that helps.

Comment: It does not change anything is there another way? For example here if my id passed in query string doesn't exist in the web service it sends me this : Unexpected character (C) at position 0.
Could not parse '' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException). Message payload is of type: String

Comment: The exception changed now. Can you post the entire stack trace? I'm wondering if the problem is actually the listener and now the requester might be working.

Answer (score 0):

Extract Error Payload using MEL #[exception]